# Automatically mounting a partition

Tags: mount, partition

I am a apprentice openSUSE user. When I turn on my laptop one of my HDD partitions are not mounted by default, so I have to open the GUI and manually click to mount it.

Is there a way to automatically mount this, from what I have read I can do it with cron job but any other solutions are accepted.

```
linux-clwa:/ # cat /etc/fstab

UUID=63d5d975-9cfe-4bfc-b71c-71079f582545 swap swap defaults 0 0
UUID=515127ed-50f2-4827-b410-f7e5e599d1b1 / btrfs defaults 0 0
UUID=515127ed-50f2-4827-b410-f7e5e599d1b1 /boot/grub2/i386-pc btrfs subvol=@/boot/grub2/i386-pc 0 0
UUID=515127ed-50f2-4827-b410-f7e5e599d1b1 /boot/grub2/x86_64-efi btrfs subvol=@/boot/grub2/x86_64-efi 0 0
UUID=515127ed-50f2-4827-b410-f7e5e599d1b1 /opt btrfs subvol=@/opt 0 0
UUID=515127ed-50f2-4827-b410-f7e5e599d1b1 /srv btrfs subvol=@/srv 0 0
UUID=515127ed-50f2-4827-b410-f7e5e599d1b1 /tmp btrfs subvol=@/tmp 0 0
UUID=515127ed-50f2-4827-b410-f7e5e599d1b1 /usr/local btrfs subvol=@/usr/local 0 0
UUID=515127ed-50f2-4827-b410-f7e5e599d1b1 /var/crash btrfs subvol=@/var/crash 0 0
UUID=515127ed-50f2-4827-b410-f7e5e599d1b1 /var/lib/libvirt/images btrfs subvol=@/var/lib/libvirt/images 0 0
UUID=515127ed-50f2-4827-b410-f7e5e599d1b1 /var/lib/mailman btrfs subvol=@/var/lib/mailman 0 0
UUID=515127ed-50f2-4827-b410-f7e5e599d1b1 /var/lib/mariadb btrfs subvol=@/var/lib/mariadb 0 0
UUID=515127ed-50f2-4827-b410-f7e5e599d1b1 /var/lib/mysql btrfs subvol=@/var/lib/mysql 0 0
UUID=515127ed-50f2-4827-b410-f7e5e599d1b1 /var/lib/named btrfs subvol=@/var/lib/named 0 0
UUID=515127ed-50f2-4827-b410-f7e5e599d1b1 /var/lib/pgsql btrfs subvol=@/var/lib/pgsql 0 0
UUID=515127ed-50f2-4827-b410-f7e5e599d1b1 /var/log btrfs subvol=@/var/log 0 0
UUID=515127ed-50f2-4827-b410-f7e5e599d1b1 /var/opt btrfs subvol=@/var/opt 0 0
UUID=515127ed-50f2-4827-b410-f7e5e599d1b1 /var/spool btrfs subvol=@/var/spool 0 0
UUID=515127ed-50f2-4827-b410-f7e5e599d1b1 /var/tmp btrfs subvol=@/var/tmp 0 0
UUID=515127ed-50f2-4827-b410-f7e5e599d1b1 /.snapshots btrfs subvol=@/.snapshots 0 0
UUID=F1D3-F389       /boot/efi            vfat       umask=0002,utf8=true  0 0
UUID=984161fa-2fbe-4519-a0f5-fb6c2a0856d6 /home                xfs        defaults              1 2
```

Comment: Do you have an entry in `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: how do I check ?

Comment: Are your partition and mountpoint showing in your `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: check the update for info

Comment: ok, so I just have to write line for the wanted partition ? if so enter an answer

Comment: and what's the partition that's not mounting?

Comment: 387587c0-73aa-498a-b5ce-234c6e5a673f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add them in the file /etc/fstab 
Here is an example :

```
UUID=35ba5186-5e5a-41e7-80b7-5247d8e06d95 /backup auto nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
```

Comment: ok, how do I know if it works and another one, all of my partitions are named "primary", how do I change that ?

Answer (score 0):

Add an entry to your /etc/fstab file
Here is detail description of the fstab format:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fstab

Basically the format is as follow:

```
<device>      <dir> <type> <options>
```